# VBA stuck in DoEvents - OfficeJS canvas addin

Tags: excel, vba, office-js

I'm trying to maintain an old tool which uses [AnalystCave's ProgressBar](https://analystcave.com/excel-animated-progress-bar/)

The code being ran is the example:

```
Sub ExampleProgressBar()
    Dim pb As ProgressBar
    Set pb = New ProgressBar
    pb.Initialize "My title", 100
    'Add 10% progress
    pb.AddProgress 10
    '...
    'Hide and remove the Progress Bar
    pb.Hide
    Set pb = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code never halts, although VBA doesn't actually freeze up. When I go to VBA dev tools and hit pause, it is clear it is processing DoEvents below:

```
Public Sub AddProgress(Optional inc As Long = 1)
'Increase progress by an increment
    Dim tl As Double, tlMin As Long, tlSec As Long, tlHour As Long, tlTotal As Long, tlTotalSec, tlTotalMin, tlTotalHour
    progress = progress + inc
    If progress > maxProgress Then progress = maxProgress
    lBar.Width = CLng(CDbl(progress) / maxProgress * maxWidth)
                '        #################################################
    DoEvents    '<<<<<<< ########### VBA Can't get passed here ###########
                '        #################################################
    tl = Time - startTime
    tlSec = Second(tl) + Minute(tl) * 60 + Hour(tl) * 3600
    tlTotal = tlSec
    If progress = 0 Then
        tlSec = 0
    Else
        tlSec = (tlSec / progress) * (maxProgress - progress)
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I tried was recompiling the entire workbook (stipped all vba modules out, saved, and re-imported all of them). This didn't cut it.

Turns out my scenario was incredibly specific. I developed this tool about 6 years ago, and previously it had an OfficeJS canvas addin which showed where the user had selected on a geospatial map. Since then the add-in has become inaccessible due to IT security etc. As a result the following Add-in error has been present for a while, but previously hasn't affected the operation of the workbook.

[image]

After removal of the canvas addin altogether and saving, DoEvents finally was completable. I assume Microsoft Office team have recently changed something about OfficeJS Canvas errors which has caused `Application.DoEvents` to eternally "freeze" (the add-in must be spawning events all the time... perhaps polling?)

So ultimately, if anyone has the same issue in the future, consider deleting your OfficeJS canvas add-ins and see if that solves the issue.